# Find Words in the List of Characters

Tags: algorithm

I have an online self-learning homework sum to do:
Find words in the list of characters.

```
eg Input: COOL
List of characters: {A,B,C,O,L,M,O,L,F} return true
Input : Book
List of characters: {A,B,C,O,L,M,O,L,F} return false (as K is not present).
Note: C found at index 2, then O should be found at index > 2 (Linear searching, search from left to right).

I could think of two solutions, both brute force.
1. Using Brute force approach to get the output
2. Using Recursion (not sure if this approach is right, however, I am expected to solve it using dynamic programming).
```

Not an expert in dynamic programming, so bear with me.
The solution I came up with :

```
  public boolean found(final String input,int n, boolean isFound, int a, String words) {

    if(n == input.length) {
        return isFound;
    }

char charValue = input.charAt(n);

for(int i = a; i<words.length-1; i++) {

   if(charValue == words.charAt[i]) {
       isFound = true;
     return found(input, n+1, true, i+1; words);
   }else {
     isFound = false;
   }
}

  return isFound;
}
```

I am not sure this solution works, need to try it on IDE. However, I am expecting this to be solved with dynamic programming. I do not see where I can save the input in cache/memory to be used again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why go for dynamic programming? You want to find if input word is present in the list of characters. I'll give you a simple and efficient approach.

```
bool is_word_present(string word, vector<char> word_list ){
    int word_index = 0;
    int word_list_size = word_list.size();
    int word_len = word.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < word_list_size && word_index < word_len; i++){
        if(word_list[i] == word[word_index]){
            word_index++;
        }
    }
    return word_index == word_len;
}
```

The question has `java` code and I gave here `C++` code. But doesn't matter as you look interested in the algorithm part of the problem. Moreover the code is self-explanatory.

Time complexity: O(n) where n is number of elements in the list of characters.

Space complexity: O(1).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was taking a course on Udemy, in the dynamic programming section, the instructor mentioned this as a Homework sum.

Answer (score 0):

Load a list of words (e.g. from The Oxford Dictionary) from file into a list.

You are going to remove words from this list as you go through it, so loop from the last index (length - 1) to the first.

Within that loop have an inner loop that goes through each letter in the word. If the current character is not in the list of permitted characters then remove the word from the list and break out of the inner loop.

I don't really see this as a dynamic programming problem. If you were checking all of the words in a book then you would store each word you check in a pass hash set or a fail hash set so you can look it up before processing each letter (i.e. a memory cache of previous results to learn from). In this case it wouldn't make it faster, it would probably slow it down as creating a hash of a string requires every character to be read anyway.

In C# you could quite easily achieve this with a single LINQ statement.

```
void Main()
{
    string[] wordsToProcess = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "bad", "cat", "dog" };
    char[] charactersToAllow = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 't', 'o', 'g' };
    List<string> qualifyingWords = 
        wordsToProcess
            .Where(w => w.All(c => charactersToAllow.Contains(c)))
            .ToList();
    qualifyingWords.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was taking a course on Udemy, in the dynamic programming section, the instructor mentioned this as a Homework sum. Even I was wondering, how could this be DP sum. I appreciate your help.

Comment: When the proposed solution is proposed to you in the course please come back and post it so we can see what your instructor had in mind.